# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter nowPlayingInfo error in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, mpnowplayinginfocenter

This works with Swift 1, but reports error in Swift 2:

```
let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: getStringForLanguage(french: "lock_en", english: "lock_fr.") as! String)!
let albumArt = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: image)
let songInfo: NSMutableDictionary = [
    MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "",
    MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "",
    MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: albumArt
]


MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = songInfo // this reports the error
```

Error message:

> Cannot assign a value of type 'NSMutableDictionary' to a value of type '[String : AnyObject]?'

Comment: Just create a Swift dictionary, not an NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: if work, thanks!         
Code final:  
let songInfo: Dictionary = [
    MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "",
    MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "",
    MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: albumArt
]
            
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = songInfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You followed my comment quite literally. :)

What I meant is that the type for `.nowPlayingInfo` is now a Swift dictionary, `[String : AnyObject]?`, instead of a `NSMutableDictionary` from Foundation.

And since Swift 2's compiler correctly infers the type of the dictionary, there's no need to declare the type.

Just write:

```
let songInfo = [
    MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "",
    MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "",
    MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: albumArt
]
```

If you need to be explicit, the right type is not `Dictionary` (although it works) but `[String : AnyObject]?`:

```
let songInfo: [String: AnyObject]? = [
    MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "",
    MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "",
    MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: albumArt
]
```

The type is an Optional because the `.nowPlayingInfo` property can be set to nil.

Comment: Thank you for the help ! I have understand something here :)